# Conver XMl file to String

Tags: java, xml, string

I am converting a xml file to string using java 
My xml is

```
<GTSRequest command="version">
<Authorization account="account" user="user" password="password"/>
</GTSRequest>
```

and Java Code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String a = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/XML/Get Current GTS Version.xml";
    System.out.println(convertXMLFileToString(a));

}

public static String convertXMLFileToString(String fileName) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));
        return stw.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but when i am converting XMl to String my out will change which is i am not want .
Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><GTSRequest command="version">
<Authorization account="account" password="password" user="user"/>
</GTSRequest>
```

there is password and user change there place alphabetically
how can i resolve this thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are transforming the XML to a document and AFTER serializating it...

If you only want the file read the file like a text file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```